# Send SMS if push notification not delivered after some delay

Tags: php, android, ios, node.js

i need some idea how to make this task.

I have an DB with push status, table named "pushStatus" with fields "id, sent, delivered"

- server send push notification on ios or android, then set pushStatus.id and pushStatus.sent = true
- phone receive this push and send callback to server about push is delivered find pushStatus.id and pushStatus.delivered = true

this is ok, but if push **not delivered** during 10sec i need to send SMS
how to do it on **NodeJS** or **PHP**

------------------UPD------------------

i think to use nodeJS with `setTimeout(sendSMS, 10000);` then in `func sendSMS` check is the pushStatus.delivered if no, call API service to send SMS, but how about high load in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You should have another column to contain timestamp for any sent push and have a `celery` task or `cron-job` which fires in 10 seconds after a push is sent, then in your task you should check status of notification and send an sms if it is not delivered.

Comment: thanks for answer, yes i think about it but in future i'll have a 1000-5000 per/hr and i need to find best solution, i read about rabbitMQ but don't know how to use in my case

Answer (score 0):

You can use below logic for implement this scenario in only **iOS**. 
Add one `NSTimer` which is run for only 10 seconds. 
Now, check your database field with this timer instance.

```
if pushStatus.delivered == true, pushStatus.id == true {
   // don't send sms.
} else {
   // send sms.
}
```

Comment: nstimer its an ios feature